# Strange behavior when using Date.setDate() incremental by day

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime

I am working on a functionality where I'd like to iterate particular dates between Date_A and Date_B.

Problem is when 'DateB' is in next month so the iterating process is overlapping to next month. Please see a line 12 of output. It seems like it starts incrementing months instead of days... Any suggestions, please? :)

1. iter: 0 , inspectedDate: Mon Apr 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
2. iter: 1 , inspectedDate: Tue Apr 23 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
3. iter: 2 , inspectedDate: Wed Apr 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
4. iter: 3 , inspectedDate: Thu Apr 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
5. iter: 4 , inspectedDate: Fri Apr 26 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
6. iter: 5 , inspectedDate: Sat Apr 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
7. iter: 6 , inspectedDate: Sun Apr 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
8. iter: 7 , inspectedDate: Mon Apr 29 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
9. iter: 8 , inspectedDate: Tue Apr 30 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
10. iter: 9 , inspectedDate: Wed May 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
11. iter: 10 , inspectedDate: Sat Jun 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
12. iter: 11 , inspectedDate: Wed Jul 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
13. iter: 12 , inspectedDate: Sat Aug 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
14. iter: 13 , inspectedDate: Wed Sep 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)

example here: https://repl.it/repls/QuerulousSelfreliantDatabase

```
const inspectedDate = new Date('2019-04-22');
const today = new Date('2019-04-22');
let intervalCorrection = 0;

for (let dayOffset = 0; dayOffset < requestInterval; dayOffset++) {
  inspectedDate.setDate(today.getDate() + dayOffset);
  console.log('iter: ' + dayOffset, ', inspectedDate: ' + inspectedDate);
}
```

Comment: what's the value of `requestInterval` variable?

Comment: `inspectedDate.setDate(today.getDate() + dayOffset);` what is the end goal of this? Because `today.getDate()` would give you `22` every time, so you actually increment with more than a single day at a time if you go over the next month boundry, then the next increment could be for `30` in which case you skip a whole month.

Comment: @ShaileshRathod it's `14` from the output. But it's not actually relevant - the problem doesn't depend on that.

Comment: Because each time you call `inspectedDate.setDate` you change the value of *inspectedDate*. When set to 31 April it rolls over to 1 May, then it's set 32 May which becomes 1 June, then 33 June which becomes 3 July, etc.

Comment: @RobG thanks for explanation why there was an output which didn't make sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'reseting' `inspectedDate` every iteration. Worked fine for me.
Changes I made to your code snippet:

```
const requestInterval = 14;
let today = new Date('2019-04-22').getDate();
let intervalCorrection = 0;

for (let dayOffset = 0; dayOffset < requestInterval; dayOffset++) {
  const inspectedDate = new Date('2019-04-22');
  inspectedDate.setDate(today + dayOffset);
  console.log('iter: ' + dayOffset, ', inspectedDate: ' + inspectedDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you `setDate` and it's more than the current month's days that changes the *month*. Adding a bigger number again changes the mongth *again*:

```js
const date = new Date("2019-02-01");
let day = 31;
let offset = 1;

date.setDate(day + offset); //goes to March
offset++;

console.log(date.toString());

date.setDate(day + offset); //goes to April
offset++;

console.log(date.toString());
```

Since you add a constant `22` (the value of `today.getDate()`) each time, you very quickly get to `30` and above which will start rolling over each month.

If you just want each consecutive day, then you don't need to have two dates and do a lot of calculations - just use a single date and increment the day by `1` each time - this will give you each day:

```js
const inspectedDate = new Date('2019-04-22');
const requestInterval = 14;

for (let i = 0; i < requestInterval; i++) {
  inspectedDate.setDate(inspectedDate.getDate() + 1); //advance one day
  console.log('iter: ' + i, ', inspectedDate: ' + inspectedDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies in that you are storing the date variable in a constant and altering its date using setDate only. This results in its moth getting changed which you are not handling.

- On iter 9, it sets the date to `22 + 9`, i.e, `31`. But the month is `4`(Apr) which is a 30 day month. So the date changes to `Wed May 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)`
- On iter 10, it sets the date to `22 + 10`, i.e, `32`. But the month is now `5`(May) which is a 31 day month. So the date changes to `Sat Jun 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)`
- On iter 11, it sets the date to `33`. The month is `6`(Jun). So the date changes to `Wed Jul 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

and so on...

I can think of 2 ways to avoid it:

#### First

Create a new variable each time

```js
const requestInterval = 14;
const today = new Date('2019-04-22');
let intervalCorrection = 0;

for (let dayOffset = 0; dayOffset < requestInterval; dayOffset++) {
  const inspectedDate = new Date('2019-04-22');
  inspectedDate.setDate(today.getDate() + dayOffset);
  console.log('iter: ' + dayOffset, ', inspectedDate: ' + inspectedDate);
}
```

#### Second

Update the month and year as well before updating date

```js
const requestInterval = 14;
const inspectedDate = new Date('2019-04-22');
const today = new Date('2019-04-22');
let intervalCorrection = 0;

for (let dayOffset = 0; dayOffset < requestInterval; dayOffset++) {
  inspectedDate.setMonth(today.getMonth());
  inspectedDate.setYear(today.getYear());
  inspectedDate.setDate(today.getDate() + dayOffset);
  console.log('iter: ' + dayOffset, ', inspectedDate: ' + inspectedDate);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, convert your date to milliseconds.
Secondly, iterate ms in day over your date.

```js
const today = new Date('2019-04-22');
let intervalCorrection = 0;
const millisecsInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

for (let dayOffset = 0; dayOffset < 14; dayOffset++) {
  const inspectedDate = new Date(today.getTime() + dayOffset * millisecsInDay);
  console.log('iter: ' + dayOffset, ', inspectedDate: ' + inspectedDate);
}
```

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so adding a fixed length of time is not a good way to increment a date a fixed number of days.

Comment: @RobG that's interesting. I checked on this fact and yeah day is really 23h56m long and Earth makes 366.25 rotations a year, therefore its rounded to 24hrs. However, machines are programmed to have exact number of ms in day and I don't see how this implementation can be inaccurate.

Comment: @RobG https://jsfiddle.net/loctary/7ef0rL8j/ check this out. It returns integer value of days since 1970-01-01 which couldn't be possible if days weren't same long

Comment: Please consider **where daylight saving is observed**. '2019-04-22' is parsed as UTC, which doesn't observe daylight saving. Per the ECMA-262, there will be an exact number of 24 hour days from the epoch to any other UTC date. So depending on the local offset and the change when daylight saving occurs (when days might be 23, 23.5, 24.5 or 25 hours long) you may get the wrong date. There are well known ways of avoiding this issue, which can cause seemingly random and difficult to find bugs.